# CSV Helper, Ignore empty Values

Tags: c#, .net, csv, parsing, csvhelper

I'm using CSVHelper to read to types of csv files:

1.

```
6000000,1,2020
6000001,1,2020
6000002,1,2020
6000003,1,2020
6000004,1,2020
```

2. 

```
6000000
6000001
6000002
```

This is my model:

```
public class Body
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }

        public int Semester { get; set; }

        public int Year { get; set; }
    }
```

This Model works fine for the first type of file. But in case of second it throws exceptions. I think it is because there are no fields for Semester and Year in CSV. Is there a way to ignore those 2 additional fields while reading that do not exist in 2nd file? I do not want to create additional Model with only Id property.

My method for reading csv:

```
public List<T> ReadFile<T>(StreamReader stream)
        {
            using (var csv = new CsvReader(stream, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
            {
                csv.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = false;
                var records = csv.GetRecords<T>().ToList();
                return records;
            }
        }
```

So if i were to read the 2nd file, then there would be returned List with Body objects but Semester and Year properties would be empty or 0

Comment: Empty values are `,,,`, the separator should be always present. Since you are using library it works correctly.

Answer (score 4):

`OptionalAttribute`:
From the CSVHelper docs:
'Ignore the member when reading if no matching field name can be found.'

Just tag your model up like this:

```
public class Body
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        [Optional]
        public int Semester { get; set; }
        [Optional]
        public int Year { get; set; }
    }
```

---

Or using a `ClassMap`:

```
public class BodyMap : ClassMap<Body>
{
    public BodyMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.Id);
        Map(m => m.Semester).Optional();
        Map(m => m.Year).Optional();
    }
}
```

Then add the following:

`csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap(new BodyMap());`

Comment: Ok, Thanks, It looks like it works with Optional, but i had to set Semester and Year as string because with int type i was getting exception

Comment: I believe you could also use a nullable int `public int? Semester`

Comment: As David Specht said - changing them to nullable ints should sort that issue too! Apologies - overlooked that one!